# How to install debian from a usb thumb drive

Tags: debian, installation, usb-flash-drive

So far I have been following the directions here
http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch04s03.html.en

I downloaded boot.img.gz to my windows machine, and copied it to my empty usb key.

At this line of instruction:

"mount the USB memory stick (mount /dev/sdX /mnt), which will now have a FAT filesystem on it, and copy a Debian netinst or businesscard ISO image to it. Unmount the stick (umount /mnt) and you are done. "

I don't have an existing debian system running.  I do have a ubuntu system, which I'm hoping this will replace.  I plugged in the usb key, and typed

"sudo dmesg | grep scsi -A 3" which another webpage told me as a way of finding where the usb key is. At the end of its output it said
"[22530852.908000] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi removable disk sdb
[22530852.908000] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0"
I think this means my usb key is 'sdb'

So now I type "sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt", and I get 'mount: you must specify the filesystem type'

I experiment a bit and try 'sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb /mnt', but this reponds 'mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
       missing codepage or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so'

Now I am stuck and don't know what else to try :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This utility](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) will do the job for you. Very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have mixed feelings about uNetBootin, however, it does work (so +1 for Laurent), however, lately I've had better results with [Pen Drive Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/).